# I tried to make a player move in pygame but it didn't work and it's giving me this error:

Tags: python, pygame

There's the error:

> ```
> File "C:/Users/jimos/PycharmProjects/ffg/app.py", line 40
>    if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
>                               ^
> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
> ```

And I followed this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w&t=53s

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon=pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Player
playerImg=pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerX=370
playerY=480
playerX_change=0

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


#game loop
running=True
while running:

    screen.fill((255, 128, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

            # if keystroke is pressed check whether its left or right
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                   playerX_change= -0.1
                if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   playerX_change= 0.1
         if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
             if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change= 0

    # 5=5 + -0.1 -> 5=5 - 0.1
    # 5=5 + 0.1
    playerX += playerX_change
    player(playerX,playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This is not a pygame error, this is an general python error, you are using wrong on this line "if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:". You probably need 2 more spaces at the starting of that line, you could have just googled the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) issue. There is 1 blank too many before the line `if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:`.
Just delete 1 leading blank to solve the issue.

```py
running=True
while running:

    screen.fill((255, 128, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

            # if keystroke is pressed check whether its left or right
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                   playerX_change= -0.1
                if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   playerX_change= 0.1

        # remove 1 bank here <----------------------------
         if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
             if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change= 0
```